# do something when function executes Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a function that is recursive for inverting colors. Here is the code:

```
function invert(id,what){
    var color = $(id).css(what);
    var matchColors = /rgb\((\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3}), (\d{1,3})\)/;
    var match = matchColors.exec(color);
    var r = (255 - match[1]).toString() + ",";
    var g = (255 - match[2]).toString() + ",";
    var b = (255 - match[3]).toString();
    answer = 'rgb(' + r + g + b + ')' ;
    $(id).css(what,answer);
};
```

So essentially I have a function that can be called in many instances (clicks of specific ids, hover on specific classes, etc.) and I do not know them all. But I need to know every single time this function gets called. How can I have an outside line of code that sets a variable equal to the amount of times the function has been called?

Comment: If you want to count the number of times the function called itself, you need to modify its source code.

Comment: there is no way to count, outside of the function, how many times a function fired if it is recursive? I find that hard to believe

Comment: @RyanSaxe it is hard to believe you cannot override an function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your *function*.

```
var wrapped = (function wrapper(present) {
    function wrapping() {
        ++wrapping.count; // increment invocation count
        return present.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    wrapping.count = 0; // counter, avaliable from outside too
    return wrapping;
}(invert));
```

If you need to call it `invert` too, re-assign `invert` after.

```
invert = wrapped;
invert.count; // 0
invert();
invert.count; // 1
invert();
invert.count; // 2
```

Comment: please re-read the question...I have made an edit so that it may be possible completely outside the original function as the function is no longer recursive

Comment: @RyanSaxe are you saying that the function `invert` is declared in a scope you don't have access to?

Comment: This works, although I am going to post a question to see if it is possible to detect becuase I am curious anyways

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your exact scenario is, but maybe you could override the function with a wrapper:

```
var invertOriginal = invert;
var counter = 0;

var invert = function(id, what, max) {
  invertOriginal(id, what, max); 

  // do counter stuff here, e.g.
  counter++; 
};
```

Comment: can't change original function

Comment: this doesn't change the original function. It simply "renames" the function and calls the renamed version. You can use this code without modifying the original source

Comment: please re-read the question...I have made an edit so that it may be possible completely outside the original function as the function is no longer recursive